# NameError Rails in Controller unitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in Ruby and follow the coder-manual course

I have this error
**NameError Rails in Controller NameError in ContactsController#new
uninitialized constant ContactsController::Contact**

here is my Contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
    end
end
```

and my view in folder app -> views -> contacts -> new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: do you have a class `Contact`?

Comment: Could you please show **contact.rb** file? It is located inside app/models folder, if there at all of course. I have a feeling it either doesn't exist or the class name inside of the file is changed and thus causing an error.

Comment: Oh yes...I don't have a model...thanks everyone...

Answer (score 1):

From the error it sounds like you're missing a model. The easiest way to create a model is through a rails generator. In your terminal navigate to the root of your project. And type

```
rails generate model Contact
```

If you wanted to add attributes to the Contact model through the generator you would type something like...

```
rails generate model Contact name:string age:integer on_facebook:boolean
```

Otherwise if you wanted to create the controller, model and restful routes you could type

```
rails generate resource Contact name:string age:integer
```

That'll create the files you need and update your routes.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Contact model also.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Some code
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @NinaPresotto, please, mark this answer as the solution. Thanks.